# Why does request.getParameter() method returns null?

Tags: java, html, mysql, http, servlets

I have a static HTML document that posts a form to a Java servlet. The servlet then takes the values of the form and forwards them to a SQL database. However, the problem is that the database claims a value to be null when I am certain that the value is not null.

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="Handler" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row uniform 50%">
    <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>
    <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row uniform 50%">
    <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row uniform 50%">
    <div class="12u">
      <textarea name="bio" id="bio" placeholder="Describe yourself" maxlength="200" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row uniform">
    <div class="12u">
      <ul class="actions align-center">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Connection c = null;
    PrintWriter op = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "root", "root");
    }catch(Exception s){
        op.println("<html>");
        op.println("<body><h1><strong>"+ "Error: "+ s +"</strong></h1></body>");
        op.println("</html>");
    }

    String username = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    String bio = request.getParameter("bio");
    String proPicName = "false";
    Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String sysTime = time.toString();

    Statement stmt = null;

    try{
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("USE dvlpr;");
        stmt.execute("INSERT INTO user_tbl (username, email, password, bio, pro_pic, last_on, date_created)" + " VALUES ("+username+", "+email+", "+pass+", "+bio+", "+proPicName+", "+sysTime+", "+sysTime+");");


        op.println("<html>");
        op.println("<body><h1><strong>Connection made! Username: " + username+ " Email: " + email+ " Your account has been created. We'll keep your password private, too. Thanks!</strong></h1>");
        op.println("</body>");
        op.println("</html>");
    }catch(Exception s){
        op.println("<html>");
        op.println("<body><h1><strong>"+ "Error: "+ s +"</strong></h1></body>");
        op.println("</html>");
    }

}
```

The error code is below:

> Error:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'username' cannot be null

**Why is this returning null?**

Comment: Switch to using [`PreparedStatement`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and your problem will likely disappear. (Otherwise each value needs to be surrounded with a single quote (`'`))

Comment: Have you inspected "username" in a debugger? Is it set or null? @MickMnemonic is right about PreparedStatements by the way.

Comment: Do you actually know that `request.getParameter` is returning null?  Or are you assuming it is because the database is throwing the error?

Comment: @MickMnemonic I will try this. But,  I must ask what is the difference? Is it somehow better optimized for queries?

Comment: When you get a chance, do a quick Google search on `SQL injection`.  I suggest you read up on that before making any more code changes.

Comment: @Brandon I am assuming since the html sends what is typed by the user.

Comment: @Brandon I am testing in a controlled environment so I don't think it's an error caused by an injected query or escape character.

Comment: Try adding a print statement to be sure.  And seriously, don't write any more code in this servlet until you read up on SQL injection and prepared statements.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that SQL injection is the reason it doesn't work.  Merely pointing out that this code is extremely vulnerable to it.  It is entirely possible that switching to prepared statements, as 2 others have suggested, would solve your bug, plus protect you against SQL injection.

Comment: You are also leaking database connections.  You should close them when finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are fine. The query isn't being executed properly because of syntax. The values themselves need to be surrounded by quotes so it should look like:

```
VALUES('"+username+"',....
```

As you can see I added one`'` before the double quotation mark and one after so the `'` will be part of the resulting String.
Just like in any other SQL insert you would do `VALUES('MyUsername', 'MyPassword',...);`.

Also you might want to use one execute method instead of 2 so it would be:

```
stmt.execute("USE dvlpr; INSERT INTO....");
```

And also there is no need for the `+` before `" VALUES`

Comment: Even though this answer in practice "fixes" the problem, the (only) correct way to do this is through parameterized SQL (i.e. using a `PreparedStatement`). Remember [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)?